# Error moving SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2005 NOLOCK Error

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, migration

I need to move a database from the  SQL Server 2000 (32 bit) to SQL Server 2005.But,When I attacted my database to SQL Server 2005,it's gives me error.(NOLOCK error)

Also , After I running dbcc check db command for database errors,I am receiving the following error.

```
Server: Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

Object ID 2: Errors found in text ID 727515136 
owned by data record identified by RID    =   (1:391:14) id = 491864819 and indid = 9.
Server: Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 2: Errors found in text ID 727646208 
owned by data record identified by RID = (1:391:16) id = 491864819 and indid = 11.
Server: Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 2: Errors found in text ID 768802816 
owned by data record identified by RID = (1:2243:15) id = 1796253504 and indid = 54.
Server: Msg 8929, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 16 consistency errors in database 'XXXXX'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, 
contact your system    administrator.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best online resource for database corruption in SQL Server world is [Paul Randal's web page](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/category/Corruption.aspx). He is our world's number one star in corruption matters. And that's because he wrote all *dbcc check* commands in SQL Server (and he's the only one who can understand them properly :-).

What I'd do in your place now would be to try the backup-restore method of moving the database to new SQL Server or try dbcc with repair option (not before making a backup of the database).

There is some good info also on MSDN about how to treat these errors. Check the article [Troubleshooting DBCC error 2570 in SQL Server 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923247).